# Trying to load a Text File that contains values from Dynamic Labels

Tags: c#, file

I'm trying to load a text file that contains values within its text file name  from dynamic label values.

My code is :

```
frm.rtxtbCurrentNotes.Text = File.ReadAllText(
        @"C:\Users\Desktop\txt Files\" + 
        frm.lblId.Text + "_" + frm.lblProject.Text+ "_.txt");
```

I keep getting the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Desktop\txt
>   Files\9F-99-8D-75-6C-17_APPC Equifax_.txt'

Comment: Paste this path in Explorer "C:\Users\Desktop\txt Files\9F-99-8D-75-6C-17_APPC Equifax_.txt", see if it opens a file or complains, If it complains you will know that file doesn't exist and hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

FileNotFoundException is thrown because the program cannot find the file at the specified path, so please ensure that the file `C:\Users\Desktop\txt Files\9F-99-8D-75-6C-17_APPC Equifax_.txt` does exist or debug your code to create the path correctly.